# How to make use of result from if statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 3 lists here. want to do a conditional combine of List 1 and 3 or 2 and 3, it seems ok when I use the following code.

```
declare @Condition varchar(10) = NULL

if @Condition IS NULL
    select * from List1
else 
    select * from List2
union 
select * from List3
```

However, If i want to store final result by inserting them into a table, it return syntax error for the if statement. is there a better way i can do this?

```
declare @Condition varchar(10) = NULL

declare @CombiList table (Value varchar(10))
insert into @CombiList

if @Condition IS NULL
    select * from List1
else 
    select * from List2
union 
select * from List3
```

Comment: You need to create two separate `INSERT` statements

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
INSERT INTO @CombiList
SELECT *
FROM   list1
WHERE  @Condition IS NULL
UNION
SELECT *
FROM   List2
WHERE  @Condition IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT *
FROM   List3
WHERE  @Condition IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create two separate `INSERT` statements for each of your condition:

```
if @Condition IS NULL
    insert into @CombiList
        select * from List1
else 
    insert into @CombiList
        select * from List2
        union 
        select * from List3
```

Answer (score -1):

In case your real issue involves more complex statements and the code can be wrapped in stored procedure, building and executing dynamic `T-SQL` statements can reduce the complexity of your code.

For example:

```
DECLARE @DynamicTSQLStatement NVARCHAR(MAX);

...

-- some statements that are executing always
SET @DynamicTSQLStatement = '....'

-- conditions

IF ... 
   SET @DynamicTSQLStatement = @DynamicTSQLStatement + '.....'
ELSE
   ...
   SET @DynamicTSQLStatement = @DynamicTSQLStatement + '.....'

EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicTSQLStatement
```